# Execution Exception : While calling method from Callable

Tags: java, scheduler

> > I am trying to run following but I am facing null pointer at userService.getName();
> >     without thread it is working fine but with thread it is throwing null pointer exception

```
         public class Sheduler implements Callable{
            private UserService userService;
            private SchedulerExecuterService scheduler=Executers.newScheduledThreadpool(2);
            @Inject
            public Sheduler (UserService userService){
             this.userService = userService;
             }

            Future future = scheduler.submit(new Callable(){
            @override
            public String call() throws Exception{
            **return userService.getName();//NUll pointer Exception**
            }
            )}

            public void startpool(){
            final Runnable beeper = new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
             UserService userService = new UserService();
             Sheduler  scd=new Sheduler (UserService userService);

            future.get();
            }
            }


            scheduleAtFixedRate(beeper,5,5,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

public static void main(){
 Sheduler  scduler=new Sheduler();
   scduler.startpool();
}
```

Comment: so, your userService is not instantiated

Comment: how do you create a `Sheduler` instance?

Comment: sorry I forgot this code
UserService userService=new UserService();
@stultuske I have instantiated it

Comment: @luk2302 In main method I have created Scheduler instance and from there I have called startpool()

Comment: where? is it in the class of which you posted code above?

Comment: yup, that is wrong, `@Inject`and `new` dont work well together.

Answer (score 0):

You use an `@Inject`on your `Scheduler` constructor but still instantiate it manually. Your `UserService` is never injected and therefore is null throwing the `NullPointerException`.